# Jetpack Compose, how to prevent text from scaling down, with higher screen density?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I am designing an app that should look the same on all display sizes (just scaled down in overall size), with JetpackCompose.

I have managed to make the text size not get affected by the font setting, but I can't get it to stay the same scale compared to the display size when changing the density (bottom slider)
the text gets smaller with higher density and bigger with lower.

Is there a way to make it scale up in size when the display changes in size too?

And yes I want it to behave that way

I tried to manually scale it depending on the density value but without luck.

This is how I managed to ignore font scaling

```
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Int = this
    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize =  value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
  }
}
```

But I haven't found a way yet to scale properly with screen density.

this is my code for the example, I created to show the issue

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().size(width = 200.dp, height = 100.dp)
    ){ 
      Text(text = "Hello World",
           fontSize = 30.sp,
           color = Color.White
           )
     }
```

Comment: You are actively making your app less accessible for your users, disadvantaging the users who are most in need. Please don't ever do this.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: In an ideal world, your approach would be universally accepted. In an ideal world, I would have hair. This is not an ideal world. The decision on whether an app will support font scaling is made by designers and/or executives. Occasionally, the developer is the designer or executive, but more often, developers are required to do what the designers and executives ask for. You're welcome to ask developers to support font scaling, and developers can advocate for it, but in the end, some developers will need code like this to keep their jobs.

Comment: "Is there a way to make it scale up in size when the display changes in size too?" -- you could look at https://github.com/Kaaveh/sdp-compose and its `ssp` unit.

Comment: this "YoU ArE MaKiNG It InAccEssible" BS is what i dont want.. this is a calculator app, i cant just rearrange all items and skale shit up, look at the original calculator app from  google WHICH ALSO SCALES like i want it .... so dont even think about saying this, the app needs to scale in size with displays, if you got a 4 inch display then  thats not my problem in 2023 @ianhanniballake

Comment: the original calculator from google dosent get affected by displaysize or font size, cause it just makes no sense.. since it would rearrange buttons in a way that make the calculator not normal.. ( nobody wants a calculator where youn have to scroll a 1x Xamount list to get from Addition to 0 or decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it working, by forcing the DP and SP to scale counteracting the displaysize or fontsize change ( and yes its still wanted to do it that way and its in no way hindering accessability, cause it is 100% not more accessible if a calculators or phone apps numberpad switches from

```
7 8 9  
4 5 6
1 2 3
0
```

to something like this

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

because the screen is all of a sudden to small to fit bigger elements or whatever...

```
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Float = ((2.625/LocalDensity.current.density)*this).toFloat()

    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize =  value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
    }
}

@Composable
fun Int.scaledDp(): Dp {
    val value: Float = ((2.625/LocalDensity.current.density)*this).toFloat()
    return value.dp
}
```

Comment: I got this same logic. But, I did not post it as "2.625" may not be the default density for all devices. It depends on the device model, manufacturer, etc.

Comment: here '2.625' is a constant that all size's compare with it. the value come's from device density

Comment: Where you got this 2.625 value from? My pixel 8 pro default density is 3.0. So if I were to apply your solution, all the dp values I would use would become smaller... On my Samsung S10+ the default density is 3.5. I don't think there's one default density. That is exactly the challenge, because you can't really apply any reasonable logic to it.